# Raster produced by Con expression not saving

Tags: python, raster, raster-calculator, arcpy, map-algebra

I cannot get a Con expression to work. Or, if it is working, I cannot get the raster produced by the Con expression to save.

I have two rasters and I want the positive difference between the two, and if any difference is negative, for that to be set to zero.

I read on the documentation that for a spatial analysis to be performed, the rasters must be cast as raster objects, which I have done by using the arcpy.Raster(raster) tool.

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

Geo_output  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
Geo_name    = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) 
SR      = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) 
InLAS   = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
pnt_spacing = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
OutFC_1     = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5) 
class_1     = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
return_1    = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7) 
OutFC_2     = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)
class_2     = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9)
return_2    = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(10)
clip    = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(11) 

OutFC   = [OutFC_1, OutFC_2]
classif     = [class_1, class_2]
returns     = [return_1, return_2]
FD_name     = Geo_name + "_Feature_Dataset"
FD_addr     = os.path.join(Geo_output,Geo_name + ".gdb") # Points to inside gdb
FC_addr     = os.path.join(FD_addr, FD_name) # Points to inside FD
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

try:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Creating Geodatabase: "+ Geo_name)
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(Geo_output, Geo_name)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Creating Feature Dataset: "+ FD_name)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(FD_addr, FD_name, SR)
    for fc,cls,ret in zip(OutFC,classif,returns):
        arcpy.AddMessage("Creating Multipoint Feature Class: "+ fc)
        result= arcpy.LASToMultipoint_3d(InLAS,os.path.join(FC_addr,fc),pnt_spacing,
            cls,ret,"#",SR,"las","1","NO_RECURSION")

        name = fc + "_Terrain"
        arcpy.AddMessage("Creating Terrain: "+ name)
        arcpy.CreateTerrain_3d(FC_addr,name,pnt_spacing,"50000","#",
        "ZTOLERANCE","ZMIN","NONE","1")
        terrain = os.path.join(FC_addr,name)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Adding Pyramids to: "+ name)
        pyramids = ["0.5 1000"]
        arcpy.AddTerrainPyramidLevel_3d(terrain,"",pyramids)
        embed = fc + "_embed"
        feature_class = "{} SHAPE masspoints 1 0 0.5 true false "\
                    "{} <None> false".format(result,embed)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Adding Feature class(es) to: "+ name)
        arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTerrain_3d(terrain, feature_class) # Insert Clip
        arcpy.AddMessage("Building: "+name)
        arcpy.BuildTerrain_3d(terrain,"NO_UPDATE_EXTENT")

        raster_name = fc +"_RAS"
        raster = os.path.join(FD_addr, raster_name)
        bitType = "FLOAT"
        method = "NATURAL_NEIGHBORS"
        sampling = "CELLSIZE 10"
        pyrLvl = 0
        arcpy.AddMessage("Terrain to Raster: " + raster)
        arcpy.TerrainToRaster_3d(terrain, raster, bitType, 
                          method, sampling, pyrLvl)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Creating Elevation Raster")
    env.workspace = FD_addr
    elev = os.join.path(FD_addr,"elevation")
    list = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "ALL")
    size = len(list) #### Make some exception here if != 2
    raster0 = arcpy.Raster(list[0])
    raster1 = arcpy.Raster(list[1])
    **elevation = arcpy.sa.Con(raster1-raster0 >= 0, raster1-raster0,0)
    elevation.save("elevation")**

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
```

I have triple checked to make sure that the raster list actually has files in it (it does!), and I have other rasters being saved to the FD_addr address, so I know that's not the problem either.

I'm new to python and arcgis. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried quite a few different ways, and none seems to work.

Help please!

Comment: You need to define a workspace for that method of .save to work.

Comment: @Aaron I defined it as     env.workspace = FD_addr towards the end of the code, but before the .save. Is this not the correct way to do it? Is there a different/better way to save?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  Try saving by a direct pathname (e.g. elevation.save("C:/temp/elevation.img") ).  Also try simplifying your Con function to make sure there is nothing wrong with your parameters (e.g. elevation = arcpy.sa.Con(raster1, 10, 1, "VALUE > 1").  If the results save, there is a problem with your Con function

Comment: @Aaron I tried both of those. Neither saving to my desktop nor simplifying my Con expression worked. I'm starting to think this is less of a "not saving" problem and more of a "not being created" problem.

Comment: Does .save work by .save("filename") or .save(output_location)?

Comment: This code is doing a heck of a lot more than a `Con` operation! After looking it over twice I still haven't even found that line. I'm *sure* you could isolate the problem better. For instance, don't execute `Con` at all and just try to create a simple, tiny constant grid. That at least would rule out the subject in your title. Assuming it still fails, start stripping stuff out: remove everything that comes after the failed command. Remove half of everything that comes before it (to the extent you can). Check for failure and iterate, using a binary search logic.

Comment: @whuber Yes, the code is doing more than a con expression, but it's the con expression that isn't working. The Con expression is performed on two rasters that are created from all that previous code. I have .las files inputted, and then the code creates a file geodatabase and a feature dataset within that geodatabase. Then, the .las files are converted to Multipoints and the Multipoints are turned into terrains. Then, the terrains are turned into rasters. These are the rasters that I need for the con expression. One is a DSM (so the canopy) and one is a DEM (ground). I need to find the

Comment: @whuber elevation difference by subtracting the DEM from the DSM. Unfortunately, do to how the data is processed before I get it, some of the information is misclassified and I get negative values. I want the Con expression to filter out the negative values and set them to zero. So, essentially, I want Con ( DSM - DEM >=0, DSM-DEM, 0). I want it to see if the difference between the DSM and the DEM is positive, if that's true, I want that difference written to the output raster. If that difference is negative (false), I want a zero written instead. I hope this clarifies!

Comment: elevation = arcpy.sa.Con(raster1-raster0 >= 0, raster1-raster0,0)

Comment: (1) My point is that by isolating the problem in your code you will make it much easier for people to read it and help you. (2) `Con` is not the best solution here: take the maximum of 0 and DSM-DEM instead. Using that alternative (or any alternative) will at least tell you whether the problem is with `con` or with something else.

Answer (score 1):

I often have trouble saving raster objects when using python scripts, which I do quite a bit.  I have developed a habit of defining the workspace immediately before the raster.save, as I have found this helps debug.  Have a look at the code below and see if it helps.

```
arcpy.AddMessage("Creating Elevation Raster")
arcpy.env.workspace = FD_addr
elev = os.join.path(FD_addr,"elevation")
list = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "ALL")
size = len(list) #### Make some exception here if != 2
raster0 = Raster(list[0])
raster1 = Raster(list[1])
difference = raster1 - raster0
elevation = Con(difference >= 0, difference, 0)
arcpy.env.workspace = FD_addr
elevation.save("elevation")
```